# Setting the path of an html file in source dir Correctly

Tags: java, java-me, lwuit

> I have a LWUIT app  that should  load and display html pages .
>
> So I have putted  a   html file in  src dir ( the same dir of my java class )

returns

> To display html files I use HtmlComponent widget.
>
> But The Html page not displayed after  application running!

returns

Is there an error in setting the path of html file ?

```
 import com.sun.lwuit.layouts.*;


     import javax.microedition.midlet.*;


     public class HelloLWUITMidlet3 extends MIDlet

     {

       public void startApp()
    {
    com.sun.lwuit.Display.init(this);

    final com.sun.lwuit.Form form = new com.sun.lwuit.Form("");

    final com.sun.lwuit.html.HTMLComponent htmlC = new com.sun.lwuit.html.HTMLComponent( );


     htmlC.setRTL(true);

    htmlC.setPage("file://ahlam.html");

    form.addComponent(htmlC);


    BorderLayout bl = new BorderLayout();

    form.setScrollable(true);


    form.show( );

   }

  public void pauseApp() 
  {

  }

 public void destroyApp(boolean unconditional) {


 }


 }
```

Answer (score 0):

To display html files inside the jar you can use

```
htmlC.setPage("jar:///ahlam.html");
```

My file was at the root of the source directory.